# Linearity in differential equation

Tags: calculus

The form $f(x)y^n(x) + ... u(x)y(x) = h(x)$ is supposed to be the definition of lineaity in diff equations. It excludes functions of y in the right hand side, but is multiplication of y by another function allowed in the right hand side allowed? It seems to be the case sometimes but not all of the time, as only composition of linear functions gives linear functions. Can't we just move it to the other side with the other y and call that form linear as well?

Comment: When you say "is multiplication of y by another function allowed", is the other function only a function of $x$ or do allow the other function to contain $y$ and its derivatives?

Comment: Either one. The result should be able to be added or subtracted to the other side.

Comment: Linearity is about *not* having terms like $y^{(i)}(x) \cdot y^{(j)}(x)$ or squares of derivatives of $y$, so this is a crucial difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can always move terms from one side of an equation to the other by subtraction.

$$  \ell_n(x) y^{(n)}(x) + \ell_{n-1}(x) y^{(n-1)}(x) + \cdots + \ell_1(x) y'(x) + \ell_0(h) y(x) + \ell_{-1}(x) = r_n(x) y^{(n)}(x) + r_{n-1}(x) y^{(n-1)}(x) + \cdots + r_1(x) y'(x) + r_0(h) y(x) + r_{-1}(x)  $$
if and only if
$$  [\ell_n(x) - r_n(x)] y^{(n)}(x) + [\ell_{n-1}(x) - r_{n-1}(x)] y^{(n-1)}(x) + \cdots + [\ell_1(x) - r_1(x)] y'(x) + [\ell_0(x) - r_0(x)] y(x) = r_{-1}(x) - \ell_{-1}(x)  \text{.}  $$